# How to use text in CGridview dropdownlist instead of values

Tags: php, gridview, yii

I'm new to Yii. I have a gridview with search boxes. One of these search boxes has to be replaced by dropdown list. Based on the dropdownlist value the value in the gridview cells should be replaced.

Suppose, I use `(0-> No Activity, 1->Pending, 2->Approved, 3-> Rejected)`. I need to replace the values 0 with No Activity, 1 with Pending, 2 with Approved, 3 with Rejected respectively both in Gridview cell and dropdownlist.

What should I mention in the value of the array

```
array(
            'name' => 'Test',
            'value' =>                  
            'filter' => array('0' => 'No Activity', '1' => 'Pending','2' => 'Approved', '3' => 'Rejected',''=>'All'),                        
            'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width: 500px;'),
            ),
```

I'm using `PHP 5.2` and `Yii version 1.13`

I edited the below code , and this works fine for me

**`EDIT :`**

```
function getTestType($test)
{
    $testTypesList = array('0'=> 'No Activity', '1'=>'Pending', '2'=>'Approved', '3'=> 'Rejected',''=>'All');
    if(is_null($test)){
        return 'All';
    }else{
        return $test=$testTypesList[$test];
    }

}
```

and in view

```
array(
            'name' => 'Test',
            'value' =>'getTestType($data->textfield)'                  
            'filter' => array('0' => 'No Activity', '1' => 'Pending','2' => 'Approved', '3' => 'Rejected',''=>'All'),                        
            'htmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width: 500px;'),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

**Controller:**

```
 $arrayList = array(0-> No Activity, 1->Pending, 2->Approved, 3-> Rejected,''=>'All');
```

Send this to view file:

```
$this->render('index',array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'arrayList'=>$arrayList, // Send array to view file
    ));
```

, and in **view** file:

```
array(           
                'name'=>'Test',
                'value'=>function ($data, $row) use ($arrayList){ return $data->name_field? $arrayList[$data->name_field] : 'All' ; },
        ),
```

**Edited: PHP 5.2**

**View:**

```
    array(
         'name'=>'Test',
         'header'=>'Test',
         'type'=>'raw',
         'value'=>'Test::getTestType($data->test)'
   ),
```

**TEST Model:**

```
public static $testTypesList = array('0'=> 'No Activity', '1'=>'Pending', '2'=>'Approved', '3'=> 'Rejected',''=>'All');
public function getTestType($test)
{
    if(is_null($test)){
        return 'All';
    }else{
        return self::$testTypesList[$test];
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm using PHP 5.2, this does not support closures. I cannot use anonymous functions

Comment: It isn't working. Screen hangs. I get syntax error in the controller.PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_PUBLIC

Comment: I did this but I get partial screen, with column names and search box

Comment: I will tell you what I have done - I added the above code in public function actionadmin()

Comment: I edited the code and found the answer. Please tell me whether I can do like this

Comment: If you already have the solution, what you need to do now? :D

Answer (score 0):

the value field in the array is what that is visible,

Daniel Vaquero is right how to determine what to show, but is you want to also filter this column with a drop down, or a text field, you should filter like this

```
'filter' => CHtml::dropDownList( array( ... ))
```

hope this helps,
cheers

Comment: I'm able to filter it. But I need to replace the values also with the corresponding words

Comment: I edited the code and found the answer. Please tell me whether I can do like this

Comment: what do you want to do?